# javascript react setting a state from a value from a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

```
const[deleteId,setDeleteId] = useState();

const PatientDeleteVarifiToggle = e =>{
    setDeleteId(e.target.value)//<<<<<--------------------------------THIS
    setDeleteState(true)
}

return (
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Doctor</th>
                    <th>Emergancy Contact</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {
                    allPatients.map((patient, i)=>{
                        return(
                            <tr>
                                <td key={i}>{patient.firstName} {patient.lastName}</td>
                                <td key={i}>{patient.doctor}</td>
                                <td key={i}>{patient.emergancyContact}</td>
                                <td><Link to={`/patientDetails/${patient._id}`}>Details</Link> | 
                                <p key={i} value={patient._id} onClick={PatientDeleteVarifiToggle}>Remove</p></td> //<<<<<<------------------------THIS
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I need to assign the `deleteId` state to the id of the patient that I'm mapping. I know that `patient._id` contains the id I want because I tested it by displaying it inside a `p` tag

Comment: Please try to include a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and, Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It seems you cut off the front of that callback function. Can you also clarify what you are trying to do? It sounds like you want to add a deleted id to the patient object.

Comment: Ah NM, it was just bad formatting that I didn't see the code correctly. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the value attribute of the p tag using `e.target.value`, if you need the value you can use `getAttribute`.

But I would suggest passing the value as an argument to the `PatientDeleteVarifiToggle` function.

I've removed the value attribute on the `p` tag and passed it as an argument using an inline arrow function.

```
<p key={i} onClick={() => PatientDeleteVarifiToggle(patient._id)}>
  Remove
</p>
```

I've also slightly modified the `PatientDeleteVarifiToggle` function.

```
const PatientDeleteVarifiToggle = (val) => {
    setDeleteId(val);
    setDeleteState(true); //<<<<<--------------------------------THIS
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<p key={i} value={patient._id} onClick={PatientDeleteVarifiToggle}>Remove</p>`

> You are passing value as an attribute of `p` tag. So you have to use getAttribute("YOUR ATTR NAME") to access The value

What you are doing

```
const PatientDeleteVarifiToggle = e =>{
    setDeleteId(e.target.value)
    setDeleteState(true)
}
```

Here `e.target.value` returns `undefined` so your state is not set correctly

If you **want to do the way you are doing then**

```
const PatientDeleteVarifiToggle = e =>{
    setDeleteId(e.target.getAttribute("value"))
    setDeleteState(true)
}
```

**common and easy way of doing this is**
As you have access to `patient._id` inside your map function. You can setState like this..

```
<p key={i} value={patient._id} onClick={() => {
    setDeleteId(patient._id);
    setDeleteState(true);
}}>Remove</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `onClick` event, the `value` attribute won't work, it will be undefined, but you can instead use the `id` attribute.

```
const PatientDeleteVarifiToggle = e =>{
  setDeleteId(e.target.id);
  setDeleteState(true);
}

...

<p id={patient._id} onClick={PatientDeleteVarifiToggle}>Remove</p>
```

Additionally, for the mapping, the React key should be on the outer-most returned element, the `tr` in this case, and since it seems you are mutating the underlying data array, using the array index will lead to reconciliation/rendering issues, use the patient `id` instead as these are likely unique within the data set and stable (they stay with the data they identify).

```
{allPatients.map((patient) => {
   return (
     <tr key={patient._id}>
       <td>{patient.firstName} {patient.lastName}</td>
       <td>{patient.doctor}</td>
       <td>{patient.emergancyContact}</td>
       <td>
         <Link to={`/patientDetails/${patient._id}`}>Details</Link> | 
         <p id={patient._id} onClick={PatientDeleteVarifiToggle}>Remove</p>
       </td>
     </tr>
   )
 })}
```